# Set navigation bar title using string variable

Tags: ios, swift, variables, navigationbar, titlebar

I'm setting my navigation bar title like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    languageMenu()

    let titleAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "AmericanTypewriter", size: 22)!]
    navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = titleAttributes
    title = "POLYGLOT"

    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: self, action: #selector(addNewWord))
}
```

Which works fine with string literals i.e, "POLYGLOT". 
I want to use a string variable called chosenLanguage, which changes value depending on what language the user chooses at startup as the value for title.

I get nothing displayed in the nav bar title area when I try this. I've not seen any examples of this in my search of the web.

The variable chosenLanguage is set in the languageMenu method like so (don't know what happened to formatting of first 2 lines!):

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

```
@IBOutlet weak var languageButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var words = [String]()
var chosenLanguage = String()
var languageSaved = String()
var toolbar = UIToolbar()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    languageMenu()

    let titleAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "AmericanTypewriter", size: 22)!]
    navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = titleAttributes
    title = chosenLanguage

    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: self, action: #selector(addNewWord))
}

@objc func languageMenu(){

    let chooseLanguage = UIAlertController(title: "Vocabulary Tutor", message: "Choose a Language", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

    let germanButton = UIAlertAction(title: "German", style: .default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
        self.chosenLanguage = "german"
        print("Choosen language is: \(self.chosenLanguage)")
        self.loadInitialValues()
    })

    let frenchButton = UIAlertAction(title: "French", style: .default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
        self.chosenLanguage = "french"
        print("Choosen language is: \(self.chosenLanguage)")
        self.loadInitialValues()
    })

    chooseLanguage.addAction(germanButton)
    chooseLanguage.addAction(frenchButton)

    self.navigationController!.present(chooseLanguage, animated: true, completion: nil)

    if let defaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.co.uk.tirnaelectronics.polyglot") {
        if chosenLanguage == "german" {
            defaults.set(chosenLanguage, forKey: "languageChosen")
        } else {
            defaults.set(chosenLanguage, forKey: "languageChosen")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: show us your chosenLanguage variable and where are you setting it

Comment: Putting a breakpoint before setting the variable might help you to debug this problem. Most likely you're not setting the variable correctly.

Comment: What is loadInitialValues?

Comment: @El Tomato It loads English and Foreign words that are programmed in from the start, rather than added by the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's currently only one place where you're setting `title`, and that's in viewDidLoad. Basically, you need to assign `chosenLanguage` to `title` every time `chosenLanguage` changes.

The reason is that strings are value types in Swift. So when you assign a variable to `title`, what you're actually doing is copying the current value of the variable into `title`. Any changes to the variable afterward do not affect `title`.

(If you were writing this in Objective-C which doesn't have value types, the same thing would happen because the `title` property uses the `copy` attribute.)

Comment: That is indeed it! I just assumed that if I'd called languageMenu before assigning chosenLanguage to title that it would work. I now realise that even if it worked once, it wouldn't re-assign it when, say, moving back and forth between other view controllers.

Comment: Glad to hear it. Make sure you mark my answer as the accepted answer when you get a chance.